# How to Convert string ("0.25500000") less than 1 to Decimal?

Tags: c#, decimal, string-conversion

I have a string `"0.30405"` and I need to convert it to a decimal. However it's throwing an error.

What is the solution for this without blowing my head off

```
Convert.ToDecimal("0.25500000") //throws exception
```

Comment: it works for me, what is the exception? I guess you used that expression somewhere in your code such as some if statement... and the exception is there in the line containing `Convert.ToDecimal`, but you thought it's caused by `Convert.ToDecimal`?

Comment: What is your culture by the way? I think it should work also but..

Comment: I would recommend using the Decimal.TryParse ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx ) function. If it fails it wont break the application, and you can handle it correctly.

Comment: What is your `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` prints?

Answer (score 8):

If that line throws an exception, it's probably because your culture settings doesn't allow comma as decimal separator.

Comment: it would be nice if you add the solution as well :)

Comment: True! ;-) I see that others have supplied the solution using InvariantCulture. Another solution might be to change the decimal sepparator in the hard coded string.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Convert.ToDecimal("0.25500000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `decimal.TryParse()` with a culture info specified.

```
decimal number;
decimal.TryParse("0.25500000", NumberStyles.Number, 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);
```

As someone pointed out in comments, in a production code you would probably want to find out if a conversion is successful by

```
if(decimal.TryParse(...))
{
    // success
}
```

Comment: @SonerGönül : but `number` can be used.